# Store finger prints in Data base using Touch Id

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8, touch-id

I am making an App where on the first screen i have login and register buttons. When i click on register it will ask for user finger prints and then user details. From here I want to store finger prints and user details in database.

And when he clicks on login. Its will open biometric scanner if finger prints matches the database finger prints he will move forward..

Is there any way is it possible to store finger prints in database. If so please give some reference links that guide me towards my goal..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-integrating-touch-id--cms-21949 this may help.

Comment: I need to fetch the finger prints and save it in a data base. Whether is it possible. Above tutorial I have seen in Appcoda with swift language.[link]http://www.appcoda.com/touch-id-api-ios8/

Answer (score 4):

You can not access the fingerprints directly. This is restricted by Apple on purpose (privacy protection). So you will not be able to store them in your database neither.

> Touch ID
>
> Your app can now use Touch ID to authenticate a user before accessing some or all content in your app. Fingerprint data is protected and never accessed by iOS or other apps. [...]

[Source: iOS 8 for Developers by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/ios8/)

Authentication is still possible using the API, but that will only return values like `Authenticated` and `Not Authenticated`, with no information about the fingerprint itself.